# update statement not working in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

```
Delimiter // 
create Procedure Update_Org_role(IN id int(11),IN role varchar(25))
begin

update Organization org set org.Role=role where org.Org_ID=id;
commit;

end;//
Delimiter ;

call Update_Org_role(123,'Company');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that argument named `role` is clashing with the column that has the same name in the table that you want to update. You can give different names to your parameters:

```
Delimiter // 
create Procedure Update_Org_role(IN p_org_id int(11),IN p_role varchar(25))
begin
    update Organization set role = p_role where Org_ID = p_org_id;
    commit;
end;//
Delimiter ;
```

Comment: yes,it worked after renaming the parameters.thank you so much